# MDX Full Last year (not to date)

Tags: ssas, mdx

I use this for LastYTD

```
ROUND(
    SUM(YTD(ParallelPeriod([Invoice Date].[Date Hierarchy].[Year]
        , 1
        , [Invoice Date].[Date Hierarchy].CurrentMember))
        , [Measures].[Revenue]
    ),
    2
)
```

Now I need full last year, not YTD. How to do that?

**UPDATE**:

II have tried following but it shows results only on Year level.

```
ROUND(
    SUM(YTD(ParallelPeriod([Invoice Date].[Date Hierarchy].[Year]
        , 1
        , ClosingPeriod([Invoice Date].[Date Hierarchy].[Year],
            [Invoice Date].[Date Hierarchy].CurrentMember)
        )
        )
        , [Measures].[Revenue]
    ),
    2
)
```

**SCREENSHOT**
[image]

Query 2:

```
ROUND(
    SUM(ParallelPeriod([Invoice Date].[Date Hierarchy].[Year]
        , 1
        , [Invoice Date].[Date Hierarchy].CurrentMember)
        , [Measures].[Revenue]
    ),
    2
)
```

Results:

[image]

UPDATE3:

This is what I need:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this with 2 calculations

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[MEASURES].[Revenue FY]
AS SUM((ANCESTOR([Date].[Y-Q-M-D].Currentmember, [Date].[Y-Q-M-D].[Year])), [Measures].[Revenue]), 
FORMAT_STRING = "#,#", 
VISIBLE = 1  ; 
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[MEASURES].[Revenue FY LY]
AS (PARALLELPERIOD( [Date].[Y-Q-M-D].[Year], 1,[Date].[Y-Q-M-D] ),[Measures].[Revenue FY]), 
FORMAT_STRING = "#,#",
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: I copied this syntax in Calculated Member field and it returns error.

Comment: If you are adding calculations in form view then you will only need the part in the second line after 'AS'. Remember to change the calculations to addapt your naming syntax. My example is based on a period hierarki named [Y-Q-M-D] in a dimension called Date. and a measure called Revenue.

Comment: Is your Invoice date dimension set to dimension type 'Time' and the attributes in your hierarki set to years, quarters, months and days ?

Comment: I have just tested this with another cube, but sadly I am not allowed to post screenshots here, so I can't show you my pivot table.

Comment: actually, you were right. I am sorry, I didn't know I can use Script in Calculations, I was using Form View all the time, that's why it didn't work. Great, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
ROUND(
    SUM(ParallelPeriod([Invoice Date].[Date Hierarchy].[Year]
        , 1
        , [Invoice Date].[Date Hierarchy].CurrentMember)
        , [Measures].[Revenue]
    ),
    2
)
```

I have just removed YTD function from your expression. On my DB this expression works fine, except the situation when we have some gaps in the date dimension (for example: 2009, 2011 members exist on level Year, but not 2010 member).

/************************************************************/

**Updated version:**
(by the comments: all members for the current year must contain value for the previous year)

```
(
   ClosingPeriod(
         [Invoice Date].[Date Hierarchy].[Year]
        ,[Invoice Date].[Date Hierarchy].CurrentMember
   ).lag(1)
   , [Measures].[Revenue]
)
```

p.s. This expression hasn't been tested yet.

Comment: nice... but the problem is that I see this value only in "Total", not in each record. Is it possible to show it everywhere? Thanks!

Comment: Just add [Invoice Date].[Date Hierarchy].CurrentMember to ClosingPeriod function.

Comment: Still nothing. Here's screenshot: http://img809.imageshack.us/img809/6628/prioryear.png

Comment: Sorry, my answer is wrong. I will try write something different later (now I don't have any possibilities to write and verify my expression).

Comment: I have tried this one also but it shows different values on different date levels...

Comment: I have uploaded screenshots for two queries. First one shows only in Total, second one is wrong

Comment: Why is the second one wrong? I don't see the total for 2010 year to compare with previous year.
"PriorYearRevenue" for 2010 year should be equal to "Revenue" for 2009 year. But you have cut the total for 2010 year...

Comment: Sorry Max, I think I was not enough clear. I need PriorYearRevenue (total, not YTD) repeat in each day level row. I have updated my question again. Thanks for your help! Btw, the second one is not "wrong" it shows YTD results in day level, I need TOTAL.

Comment: "Shall we show the same values for the months and quarters?" - Yes

Comment: I haven't deleted my previous expression... :) Please look at the second part of my answer.

Comment: It's still only in the total (for year), nothing in day level... it's starting to get interesting :)

Comment: OK, I'll check this expression and write you tomorrow (now I write it like on the "paper").